# Symfony generate template with -%. Whats does it mean?

Tags: symfony, twig, crud

i have generate a minimalistic crud-app. In all templates that was generated the block body has **-%**

```
{% block body -%}
```

Is this correct or what it mean? I know only this one

```
{% block body %}
```

If i change it, nothing is impact.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New response** :

According to the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control) :
It tells Twig to remove spaces between `{% block body -%}` and next HTML tag.

Example :

```
{% block body -%}
     <p>...</p>
{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

will output :

```
<p>...</p>
        </div>
```

Spaces between `block` Twig tag and `p` HTML tag are removed.

See fiddle for more examples : http://twigfiddle.com/w5nd3m

**Former wrong response**

<strike>It [tells Twig to not generate spaces up to closing `{% endblock %}` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control).</strike>

This is a short form for

```
{% block body %}
{% spaceless %}
...
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link. Interested information about this ;)

Comment: Are `{% block body **-**}` and `{% spaceless %}` redundant in your example?